# Access files from project folder in UWP

Tags: visual-c++, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

in my solution I have backgroundtask project which has a "Resources" directory. How can I acess the files of this directory?

I already tried

```
auto loader = Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResourceLoader::GetForViewIndependentUse();
```

and I get a "ResourceMap Not Found" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Package^ package = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current;
Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ installedLocation = package->InstalledLocation;
```

this should return the Folder of your project that contains your "Resources" folder.